# How use a DocumentPaginator asynchronously via GetPageAsync with XpsDocumentWriter?

Tags: wpf, xpsdocument, documentpaginator

The idea here is that I have a DocumentPaginator that I want to use with an XpsDocumentWriter or PrintDialog as both have the option of printing given a paginator. When I use either, i.e. XpsDocumentWriter.Write[Async] or PrintDialog.PrintDocument, the paginator is accesed via GetPage vs. GetPageAsync which I've overridden in derived DocumentPaginator class.

Outside of manually consuming the paginator and feeding Visuals to the document writer, is there a way to trigger the use of the Asyc functions of a DocumentPaginator?